# @XmlIDREF not seeing hierarchy when marshalling to XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, hierarchy

I'm very new at XML and I'm having a problem I'm not able to solve and after looking around for hours I've decided to post my problem.

I'm using @XmlIDREF to just have the XmlID of some java classes on the XML doc.
All works fine, but when JAXB looks for the ID depeen on the tree hierarchy it seems that it couldn't find it and marhsalls the whole object again.

I'll show you the (simplified) model, it's all about optical routers, java classes represent the router and some components:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class OpticalRouter {
    // @XmlID inherited from upper class
    private List<FiberConnection> fiberConnections = new ArrayList<FiberConnection>();
}
```

That's a fiber connection:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)   
public class FiberConnection {  

    @XmlID
    private String instanceID;  

    @XmlIDREF
    Card card;              

    @XmlIDREF
    Port port;

    @XmlIDREF
    Channel channel;
}
```

And finally:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({ 
        DropCard.class,
        AddCard.class
})
public class Card{
    // @XmlID inherited from supper class    
}
```

All works fine when I marshall **ports** and **channels** due they don't have subclasses.... but when it's time to marshall the **cards** if it's an AddCard or a DropCard it marshalls it another time instead of using the IDREF.
It seems that JAXB doesn't find them on the hierarchy...

If I change the original "Card card;" of FiberConnection for an "AddCard" for example it works too (JAXB finds the IdREF and doesn't marshall it again).

Hope I have explained that clearly.
Ask if not, I'll be glad to answer :)

Thanks in advance!

---

---

**EDITED**

Ok, I've come back with new info and results to explain myself better.

Due it's a huge class model and I don't want to make the post to much difficult to read I have created a kind of UML class diagram to make it much easier to read with some important info that should help (XML annotations and parameters). I have also included @XmlElement tags as Blaise advised me (thanks again).

- Here you can find the **yEd UML archive**: [yEd file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByAo__T15L1FbDhNNlRXYjNScW8/edit?usp=sharing)
- And there an **UML jpg** if you don't have/want to download graph
  editor:  [jpg file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByAo__T15L1FOFA0QmdZc1B3cmM/edit?usp=sharing)

I also include (to finish) a part of the XML to better see what's happening.

Here I have a fiberConnection as the above mentioned.

I have a **scCard** and a **fiberChannelPlan** that have **already been marshalled before** on the XML doc (checked) but **they are being marshalled again**...

In exchange, **srcPort**, **srcChannel** and **fiberChannels**, also marshalled before, have only their ID's.

```
<OpticalRouter>
 <fiberConnections>
        <instanceID>FiberConnection@29e83b01</instanceID>
        <srcCard xsi:type="DropCard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">                        
            <instanceID>DropCard@6b02b23d</instanceID>            
            <type>11</type>
            <subtype>1</subtype>
            <chasis>0</chasis>          
            <fiberChannelPlan xsi:type="ChannelPlan">
                <instanceID>ChannelPlan@7e246b6d</instanceID>
                <firstChannel>0</firstChannel>
                <lastChannel>0</lastChannel>                
                <maxFreq>196.1</maxFreq>
                <minFreq>191.6</minFreq>                                
                <fiberChannels>Channel/360</fiberChannels>
                <fiberChannels>Channel/368</fiberChannels>
                <fiberChannels>Channel/376</fiberChannels>
                <fiberChannels>Channel/384</fiberChannels>
            </fiberChannelPlan>            
            <cardExpressPort>Port@4f781d1d</cardExpressPort>
            <carCommonPort>Port@56bf83ad</carCommonPort>
        </srcCard>
        <srcPort>Port@56bf83ad</srcPort>
        <srcChannel>Channel/184</srcChannel>
    </fiberConnections>
</OpticalRouter>
```

I think that the problem is something related to that post I found (even if I'm using linux and java 1.6) or other posts I have seen here on StarckOverflow:
java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-870

Thanks in advance!

P.S: all code I'm using is opensource and can be downloaded from the main source at a git repository if someone thinks it should be easier for him.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but I don't see any members here called `ports` or `channels` - are these collections of some sort that you haven't shown  us?

Comment: Nop. I forgot to post it, but **Port** and **Channel** are both classes like **Card**.

I've been making some tests and I will update the post with more info.

Thanks Peter!

Comment: Still making some tests and nothing...

Anybody knows if overriding marshal function I could change the ID in some way that IDREF see it??

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that each object in your graph is referenced through a containment/nesting relationship (such as `@XmlElement`), this forms the XML.  I don't see where this requirement is met in your model.  Then you can use `@XmlID/@XmlIDREF` to have key based relationships within the tree to turn it into a graph.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise, I didn't know that.
I will try it and come back with the results.

Kind regards.